# Project is not compiling because of `@withGesture`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code that compiles just fine in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2455jj0wwp). However if I clone and npm install and then try to run it locally, I get a compile error:

```
Failed to compile.
./src/index.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (9:0)

   7 | import './styles.css'
   8 |
>  9 | @withGesture // https://github.com/drcmda/react-with-gesture
     | ^
  10 | class Slider extends React.Component {
  11 |   render() {
  12 |     const { xDelta, down, children } = this.props
```

react-with-gesture module shows different ways of using it, but I am wondering why I am getting compilation error an if there's a way to prevent it. Appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-scripts` maintainers [decline to support decorators](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/167).  I don't know what CodeSandbox is doing that makes this work.  One alternative is [custom-react-scripts](https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a).  Or you can just use a function call instead of a decorator:

```
class OrigSlider extends React.Component {
  // ...
}
let Slider = withGesture(OrigSlider);
```

When I do that, I get an unrelated error that looks like an incompatibility between `@babel/runtime` and `react-spring`.  Upgrading to the latest `react-spring` got the server running for me.  [Final codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0xz200x7z0).